Is it possible to use the verb "fill" with the word "shortage"?
Can we use the verb "fill" to mean "compensate" when we are talking about shortage of something? For example, can we say "We can fill each other's shortages"?

What do you mean by "shortage".  Do you mean if you have no rice and he has no beans, then he gives you some rice and you give him beans.  Or do you mean personal abilities? Like a shortage of a skill in something?  What sort of situation?  This is a figurative use of "fill"

They are not collocated, it is better to say: "We can fill each other's gaps" or "We can complete each other's gaps".

What's wrong with "compensate" and instead of "shortage" I'd say "weaknesses".  We can compensate each other's weakness You must however provide solid examples, words in English are used differently according to context. The question needs more detail, and I loved to know who is upvoting so many questions recently that lack effort and any sort of detail/research/source etc

I have no problem with filling a shortage – there may be other words that would be more precise (alleviate, reduce, mitigate, etc.), but it’s perfectly clear and understandable; e.g., “The aid is intended to fill the food shortage in the area”. But your example sentence is very strange, and not because of the choice of verb. In “We can X each other’s shortages”, I can’t think of any verb that would make the sentence make sense without having to think up highly specific contexts. People may have shortcomings, but they don't generally have shortages.


We can compensate for each other's weaknesses.
We can make up for each other's lack of experience.
We can fill in for each other's shortcomings.


Hi everyone. I mean shortages both in "personal abilities" and "mental strength". For example, someone faces a difficult problem and is unable to make a decision on it. At this point, the second person comes and helps him or her to decide; and vice versa.

These verbs can be used when cooperation of two or more people can achieve a better outcome than one person alone, because that lone person lacks something -- whether it be experience, skills, knowledge, mental fortitude,  emotional resolve, whatever it might be.

BTW, we normally use the word shortage with commodities that can be in short supply. It isn't used, except ironically, of qualities like mental fortitude or moral integrity, and when used ironically, it expresses a kind of disdain or criticism.  It appears moral integrity is in short supply in that political faction. There's definitely a shortage  these days.

With respect to the more common use of shortage - when used in conjunction with a commodity - rather than fill, one would be more likely to use  the word satisfy, for example

Rice has been imported to satisfy the shortage that has been created by the on-going drought.

Saying

Rice has been imported to fill the shortage that has been created by the on-going drought.

just sounds odd.
